# Nintendo DS Controller Mod - Daisy Chain issue

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, signal-integrity

This is my first project I've taken on, and honestly it has all gone well until this point and I've learnt so much.

I've gotten permission from the person who [designed the PCB](https://3dscapture.com/controller/), Loopy from 3DSCapture, to post about it.

It's a simple enough PCB, you connect the pinouts from the DS to the chip and it exports it to a 6 pin connection. From there, you can choose whatever controller you want to talk to it. I've installed this little mod chip into two original Nintendo DS' and hooked them both up to an SNES controller with a little daisy chain connection.

It works perfectly on its own when *only one* of the consoles is attached to the SNES controller, but when two are attached I get random "button" presses like A or the Right Shoulder button. This also happens with other controllers, like GameCube, etc. So I don't believe it's anything to do with the SNES controller. And I've tested a few pairs to be certain.

I can only assume this is data interference from the mod chips interacting with each other? But I don't know enough to troubleshoot what could be the issue. If it helps, the CPUs on the microcontrollers are ARM Cortex-M0.

I know of someone who made a hub, with presumably an arduino, between the daisy chained DS consoles and the SNES controller. But, understandably, he doesn't wish to share his design. So I don't know how he overcame this issue.

Really, thank you for any help and ideas! I apologize for not being more knowledgeable.